# Comparing values between lines within a group

Tags: spss

I'm looking to create a column denoting if a survey respondent has changed locations from Wave 6 to Wave 7. I do not care about previous waves (although they are there in the data). 
So the logic I want is: If the email from Wave 6= the email from Wave 7 and location from 6 <> location from 7 then 1. So I'm only concerned about respondents that show up in both waves 6 and 7.

Here is an example of the output that I would want: (I want the 1 to appear both on Wave 6 and Wave 7, denoting the change for both waves).

[image: <code>enter code here</code>]

I'm unsure how to logically write this in SPSS. Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do this, so here's one that should work assuming there is only one occurrence of every `wave` X `Email_A` combination:

```
sort cases by Email_A wave.
compute changeLocation=
   (Email_A=lag(Email_A) and wave=7 and lag(wave)=6 and location<>lag(location)).
```

at this point you have the 1 in every relevant row of `wave=7`. Now to get this to the `wave=6` rows there are also a few ways but here's a fun one:

```
sort cases by Email_A wave (d).
if Email_A=lag(Email_A) and wave=6 and lag(changeLocation)=1 changeLocation=1.
```

Comment: Amazing...as always, thanks so much for your help!! Thats just what I needed